# How to Split BootStrap Badge On Multiple Line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Ref: [BootStrap badge](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/).

By default items are split based on comma. However on pressing enter I am in need to put each item on the new line.

Comment: put badge inside <div>

Comment: You should provide even a little piece of code which shows us what you've tried and where we could exactly help you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bootstrap badges](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/) are `span` elements which means they are displayed `inline` by default. If you want to display sequential badges on new lines then you can either wrap them in a block element such as a `div`:

```
<div>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Badge 1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Badge 2</span>
</div>
```

or apply your own style:

HTML:

```
<span class="badge badge-secondary block-badge">Badge 1</span>
<span class="badge badge-secondary block-badge">Badge 1</span>
```

CSS:

```
.badge.block-badge {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Was wondering is it feasible to capture user input using BootStrap badge. Something like this in Material. https://plnkr.co/edit/zqRh4UZejke8RBTCBBm2?p=preview

Comment: That's just Javascript, nothing to do with Bootstrap. Plenty of libraries out there that will do this for you, go have a search :)